# Perforce Server 2020 Giving Problems On Multiple Logins

Tags: perforce, p4java

On migrating from 2015 perforce server to 2019, i was facing parrallel login issues from Java API for P4, P4JAVA.

On 2019 server ,if multiple IServer objects( say `server1` and `server2`) made connection to the server using same userId, then logging out of server1 (i.e. `server1.logout()`) ends session for all other IServer objects concurrently logged in.

This does not happen for 2015 server and ending seesion for server1 using logout doesn't result in the same for server2.

Is this the expected working for 2019 server? Can changing any properties revert 2019 authentication to work similar to 2015 server?
I have attached a piece of code below and output for further reference

```
  public static void main(String args[]) throws P4JavaException, URISyntaxException {
    IOptionsServer server1 = null, server2 =null;
    server1 = connectServer(server1,"p4javassl://127.0.0.1:1666");
    server2 = connectServer(server2,"p4javassl://127.0.0.1:1666");
    System.out.println(server1.getLoginStatus());
    System.out.println(server2.getLoginStatus());
    server1.logout();
    System.out.println(server1.getLoginStatus());
    System.out.println(server2.getLoginStatus());
  }
  public static IOptionsServer connectServer(IOptionsServer server,String URL)
      throws P4JavaException, URISyntaxException {
    Properties defaultProps = new Properties();
    defaultProps.put(RpcPropertyDefs.RPC_SOCKET_SO_TIMEOUT_NICK, "90000");
    defaultProps.putAll(System.getProperties());
    server = ServerFactory.getOptionsServer(URL, defaultProps);
    TrustOptions trustOptions = new TrustOptions(true, false, true);
    ((IOptionsServer) server).addTrust(trustOptions);
    server.connect();
    server.setUserName("usr");
    server.login("pass");
    return server;
  }
```

**Output for 2019 server**

> User super ticket expires in 11 hours 59 minutes. User super ticket
>   expires in 11 hours 59 minutes. Perforce password (P4PASSWD) invalid
>   or unset.
>
> Perforce password (P4PASSWD) invalid or unset.

**Output for 2015 server**

> User super ticket expires in 11 hours 59 minutes. User super ticket
>   expires in 11 hours 59 minutes. Perforce password (P4PASSWD) invalid
>   or unset.
>
> User super ticket expires in 11 hours 59 minutes.

Comment: The difference may be that P4Java defaults to `logout -a` rather than a regular `logout`?  Check the docs and see if there's an option to do a logout that clears the local ticket without invalidating the server-side ticket.

Comment: @Samwise by default , `logout` happens over `logout -a`, I have verified this. This can be controlled using LoginOptions. This looks more like there is some change in internal functioning of authentication in server 2019 from 2015

Comment: Ah, maybe the difference is that now they're sharing the same ticket file?   Does P4Java let you configure the ticket file location?

Comment: I am not aware of how ticket files work for login/authentication , but I do not believe that to be the issue as well.  I believe so because I  logged in and logged out from a different machine, and the logout from the different machine also ended my session on current machine

Comment: @Samwise also if it helps , i have set the TLS security to 1.2 for server

Answer (score 0):

All client-side tickets are stored in a ticket file (`P4TICKETS`), keyed by username and server port.  You can see all your tickets by running the `p4 tickets` command.

When you do a `p4 logout`, the ticket for the current user/port is deleted from the local tickets file, requiring you to `p4 login` again to get a new copy of it from the server.  Since a regular `logout` doesn't invalidate the ticket on the server, you can remain "logged in" as long as you keep a copy of the ticket; you could do this by having multiple tickets files, or by simply saving the hash and then restoring it (you can also pass a ticket hash as `P4PASSWD` if it's not in the tickets file).